# How to get subfolders and files using gitlab api

Tags: gitlab

I am using gitlab api to get the files and folders and succeded,

But I can able to get only directory names, not its subfolders and files.

So, how can i get full tree of my repository.

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Mallikarjuna

Comment: What command are you currently using to get the directory names?

Comment: Hi @VonC,I am using get method like `GET /projects` to get projects related to auth token

Answer (score 12):

According to the [Repositories API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html), we can use

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/tree
```

To list files and directories in a project. But we can only get the files and directories in top-level of the repo in this way, and sub-directories of directories in top-level with param `path`.

If you wanna get directories of `script/js/components`, for example, you can use

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/tree?path=script/js/components
```

Comment: @rwking Thank you for your reminder. I find out the way to traversing the tree and update my answer.

Answer (score 8):

#### Rest API

You can use the [recursive option](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/repositories.html#list-repository-tree) to get the full tree using /projects/:id/repository/tree?recursive=true

For example : https://your_gitlab_host/api/v4/projects/:id/repository/tree?recursive=true&per_page=100

#### GraphQL API

You can also use the recently released [Gitlab GraphQL API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/) to get the trees in a recursive way :

```graphql
{
  project(fullPath: "project_name_here") {
    repository {
      tree(ref: "master", recursive: true){
        blobs{
          nodes {
            name
            type
            flatPath
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can go to the following URL : https://$gitlab_url/-/graphql-explorer and past the above query

The Graphql endpoint is a POST on "https://$gitlab_url/api/graphql"
An example using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```bash
gitlab_url=<your gitlab host>
access_token=<your access token>
project_name=<your project name>
branch=master

curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "{ project(fullPath: \"'$project_name'\") { repository { tree(ref: \"'$branch'\", recursive: true){ blobs{ nodes { name type flatPath }}}}}}"
      }' "https://$gitlab_url/api/graphql" | jq '.'
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a limit to how many tree-items can be returned in a single call?

Answer (score 1):

You should do URL encoding to the full path of the file. For example, let's assume that the path to file in your repository is: javascript/header.js

Then you could use:

```bash
curl --head --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://<<your Gitlab url>>/api/v4/projects/<your project id>/repository/files/javascript%2Fheader%2Ejs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, as mentioned in other responses, you have missed the `path` attribute of the [gitlab repositories API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#list-repository-tree) which lets you browse the file hierarchy.

In addition, for simplicity, the python gitlab project exposes it through the [projects API](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/projects.html#).  Example:

```
# list the content of the root directory for the default branch
items = project.repository_tree()

# list the content of a subdirectory on a specific branch
items = project.repository_tree(path='docs', ref='branch1')
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the whole tree with sub-directories and files, you can pass a parameter called "**recursive**" to **true**

By default it's false

Api - {Gitlab_URl}/api/v4/projects/{Project_id}/repository/tree?recursive=true

Thanks!

Comment: Please make more obvious what additional insight you provide beyond stackoverflow.com/a/58572140/7733418 Currently it looks like you are saying thanks for that answer, which is not accepted as an answer post on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, this script will do the job. Of course, you need to define projectId and token

```js
async function getListFilesFromRepo(projectId, privateToken, path) {
  const url = `${gitLabApiUrl}/projects/${projectId}/repository/tree?path=${encodeURIComponent(path)}`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'PRIVATE-TOKEN': privateToken,
    },
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    const data = await response.json();

    const promises = data.map(e => {
      if (e.type === 'blob') {
        return e.path;
      } else if (e.type === 'tree') {
        return getListFilesFromRepo(projectId, privateToken, e.path);
      }
    });

    const result = await Promise.all(promises);
    return result.flat();
  } else {
    throw `An error occurred while fetching: ${url}`;
  }
}


(async() => {
  const filesList = await getListFilesFromRepo(projectId, privateToken, '');
  console.log(filesList);
})()
```